# Compile PHP OCI8 extension under Alpinelinux

Tags: php, oracle, oci8, alpine-linux

I'm trying to compile [PHP OCI8 extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) and run it under [Alpinelinux](http://alpinelinux.org/). But it seems extension has some dependencies on symbols defined in `glibc` but missing in [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/).

Is there any existent compiled PHP OCI8 extension I can use? Or is there any workaround to make oci8 extension and oracle instant client work with alpinelinux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution for Alpine turned out to be simple: use Instant Client v11 (11.2.0.4) instead of v12 (12.2.0.1):

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/instantclient
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/local/instantclient

# Install Oracle Client and build OCI8 (Oracle Command Interface 8 - PHP extension)

RUN apk add php7-pear php7-dev gcc musl-dev libnsl libaio &&\
## Download and unarchive Instant Client v11
  curl -o /tmp/basic.zip https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bumpx/oracle-instantclient/master/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip && \
  curl -o /tmp/sdk.zip https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bumpx/oracle-instantclient/master/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip && \
  curl -o /tmp/sqlplus.zip https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bumpx/oracle-instantclient/master/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip && \
  unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/basic.zip && \
  unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/sdk.zip && \
  unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/sqlplus.zip && \
## Links are required for older SDKs
  ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_11_2 ${ORACLE_HOME} && \
  ln -s ${ORACLE_HOME}/libclntsh.so.* ${ORACLE_HOME}/libclntsh.so && \
  ln -s ${ORACLE_HOME}/libocci.so.* ${ORACLE_HOME}/libocci.so && \
  ln -s ${ORACLE_HOME}/lib* /usr/lib && \
  ln -s ${ORACLE_HOME}/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus &&\
  ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2.0.0  /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 &&\
## Build OCI8 with PECL
  echo "instantclient,${ORACLE_HOME}" | pecl install oci8 &&\
  echo 'extension=oci8.so' > /etc/php7/conf.d/30-oci8.ini &&\
#  Clean up
  apk del php7-pear php7-dev gcc musl-dev &&\
  rm -rf /tmp/*.zip /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/pear/
```

Comment: I used `docker-php-ext-configure` and `docker-php-ext-install` to build the extension rather than `pecl` - this saved installing and removing a lot of packages.

`RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,$ORACLE_HOME && docker-php-ext-install oci8`

Comment: @Rick for some reason we use pure alpine as base image, rather than official PHP image, so ```docker-php-ext-configure``` doesn't work for me, otherwise - yes, it may be easier.

Answer (score 4):

Try these commands.

It works under Docker on Alpine.

But, you have to install the GLIB Alpine compatibility layer: https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc

```
# Install OCI8
COPY ./oracle-sdk /tmp/oracle-sdk
RUN apk add --no-cache libaio-dev && \
unzip /tmp/oracle-sdk/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
unzip /tmp/oracle-sdk/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
unzip /tmp/oracle-sdk/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_12_2 /usr/local/instantclient && \
ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.* /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so && \
ln -s /usr/local/libclntshcore.so.* /usr/local/instantclient/libclntshcore.so && \
ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libocci.so.* /usr/local/instantclient/libocci.so && \
ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus && \
docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient && \
docker-php-ext-install oci8 && \
rm -rf /tmp/oracle-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

People who've tried Alpine haven't found a way.  The problem is not specific to PHP, so check other languages that also use Oracle Instant Client and have tried Alpine.  For example, see the Alpine issue https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/31

Comment: Yep, I was expecting it to be related with Oracle and their dependency on non-standard glibc calls. Apparently there is no way to get it working at the moment. Thanks for your comment anyway :)

Comment: Let me know too if something new would happen with problem

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM php:alpine3.13

RUN apk add --no-cache composer libaio libc6-compat \
 && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip -O- | busybox unzip -q - \
 && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip -O- | busybox unzip -q - \
 && cp /instantclient_21_1/libclntsh.so.21.1 /instantclient_21_1/libclntsh.so && cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /instantclient_21_1/ && cp /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 \
 && docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/instantclient_21_1 && docker-php-ext-install oci8
```